# how to call .cls file in TexStudio

Tags: document-classes

I am trying to use "asaproc" document class with `\documentclass[11pt]{asaproc}` in my LaTeX file. I use Texstudio in my computer with Windows 10 system. Miktex2.9 is also installed in my computer. The file `asaproc.cls` is also placed in the same directory. But the error message says that File `assproc.cls` not found. Is this the right place for `asaproc.cls`?  What is the file type for `assproc.cls`? How to let LaTeX to find this file?

Comment: See **https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063** or **https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137**. The question has nothing to do with your tex editor (TexStudio).

Comment: Check your spelling! You totally about having one class in your dir but the name you mention that is missing has a different name